# how to make as a label from a part of my form which is resizeable and movable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a part of created form as a label after clicking button "create" and it should be resizable and movable later... please tel me the code either in html or javascript or jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood, you want to click on a button and create a label (like a popup) that can be resizable and movable.

You can use JQuery plugins to do that. For example:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog